# change JProgressBar color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jprogressbar

How can I change the color of `JProgressBar` in java?
Java is using nimbus look and feel by default.

Some stackoverflow answers showed some very complex code using painters.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Wait. You want to change the progress bar color in a java application you made using netbeans or to the netbeans progressbar itself?

Comment: I mada a jframe with a progress bar in netbeans

Comment: So your question is wrong, java has nothing to do with netbeans itself.